# Is there a limit in the text length that you can use as a parameter for an exe file?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am currently using this code to pass some parameters to an exe file:

```
Dim args As String() = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
```

This mean that I can use these command line: "myApp.exe toto" or "myApp.exe tutu" ti display different things.

This is working fine and I am please with it.

I just wanted to know if there is a limit in the text that I can pass? Is that limited by VB code,n Visual Studio, or Windows?

I planned to send some long text, and would like to know if there are some limitations or not.

I cannot find anything by looking at the help or by googling.

Documentation can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you tag [tag:vb.net] question as [tag:vb6]? Are you interested in both?

Comment: I know this is some VB, but I don't know exactly which one is this.. I am pretty new to Visual Studio and tried some little programs. I removed the tag.

Comment: No probs, there's still a good chance that ultimate answer is the same for [tag:vb6] too. I'm just not sure from the top of my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maximum of 32768 characters for any environment string used as a command-line argument

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdzat713(v=vs.80).aspx